# Split string and get Second value only

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

I wonder if it's possible to use split to divide a string with several parts that are separated with a comma, like this:

```
10,12-JUL-16,11,0
```

I just want the Second part, the 12-JUL-16 of string and not the rest?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes:

```
var result = str.Split(',')[1];
```

OR:

```
var result = str.Split(',').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR (Better performance - takes only first three portions of the split):

```
var result = str.Split(new []{ ',' }, 3).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ's `Skip()` and `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` if you are not sure there is a second item:

```
string s = "10,12-JUL-16,11,0";
string second = s.Split(',').Skip(1).First();
```

Or if you are absolutely sure there is a second item, you could use the array accessor:

```
string second = s.Split(',')[1];
```

Comment: Does Skip has a parameterless overload ?

Comment: No. It does not ;) @user3185569

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way though the rest have already mentioned it.

```
string input = "10,12-JUL-16,11,0";
string[] parts = input.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
```

Output:

```
12-JUL-16
```

[**Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhTErz)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `String.Split`, it has an overloaded method which accepts max no of splits.

```
var input = "10,12-JUL-16,11,0"; // input string.

input.Split(new char[]{','},3)[1]
```

Check the [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4I6oxk)

Comment: suggestion: provide demo input string that actually works (has a second part) ;-)

Comment: This doesn't compile .

Comment: @user3185569 forgot to specify char array, updated it,Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Whomever down voted can you please remove it if the edit is correct?

Comment: @Shneeg ahh...that wass caused by max splits I specified as 2. updated it, check the demo. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can:

```
string[] parts = str.Split(',');
```

Then your second part is in `parts[1]`.

or:

```
string secondPart = str.Split(',')[1];
```

or with Linq:

```
string secondPart = str.Split(',').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
if (secondPart != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ... 
}
```

Also you can use not only one symbol for string splitting, i.e.:

```
string secondPart = str.Split(new[] {',', '.', ';'})[1];
```